# Access Keychain Access password generator (password assistant) via Terminal without the user interface

Tags: terminal, keychain

Is it possible to access, the "password assistant" also known as the password generator located inside the Keychain Access via terminal or otherwise?

Steps to access in UI:

- Launch Keychain Access
- New password item
- Select padlock item (generate password)
- Create random password according to security level

Answer (score 9):

Your exact question [has been asked on Stackoverflow in 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936161/1256347). The answers did not provide a way to access the Keychain password generator, but did suggest some alternatives.

A Google search for `mac terminal password generator` also shows several ways to generate a password from Terminal. I have listed a couple below.

```
openssl rand -base64 6
```

You can change `-base64` to `-hex` to limit the use of special characters. The `6` indicates the lenght of the password.

```
env LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc "a-zA-Z0-9-_\$\?" < /dev/urandom | head -c 10
```

The `"a-zA-Z0-9-_\$\?"` part indicates allowed characters and the `10` defines the length.